# Automatically convert pointer/iterator to const in template function

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, iterator, constants

I'm trying to make a function that works on both pointers and iterators (I want to have the checkedness of iterators over collections during testing and the flexibility to use arrays to expose a C library without wrapping).  I want to do this using as little boiler-plate code as possible and without relying on Boost or C++11 features.  Ok I don't, my requirements specification does.

So far the solution is quite simple: a function template parametrizing on the iterator.  The problem is that I want the iterator to refer to const values; in part to avoid stupid mistakes (changing something that is strictly an input value) and in part to allow the compiler to use constness for optimization (the values are used in tight loops where every optimization is welcome.

Consider this example:

```
void foo(vector<int>::const_iterator it)
{
        //it[5] = 7; // 1
        int tmp = it[5];
}

void bar(const int *it)
{
        //it[5] = 7; // 2
        int tmp = it[5];
}

template<class T>
void baz(T it)
{
        it[5] = 7; // 3
        int tmp = it[5];
}

template<class T>
void qux(T it)
{
        //it[5] = 7; // 4
        int tmp = it[5];
}

template<class T>
void quux(const T it)
{
        it[5] = 7; // 5
        int tmp = it[5];
}

vector<int> a(10);
const vector<int> b(10);
int c[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
const int d[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

foo(a.begin());
foo(b.begin());
bar(c);
bar(d);
baz(a.begin());
//baz(b.begin()); // 5
baz(c);
//baz(d); // 6
qux(a.begin());
qux(b.begin());
qux(c);
qux(d);
quux(a.begin()); // 7
//quux(b.begin()); // 8
quux(c);
//quux(d); // 9
```

Foo and bar work as intended; I can read values and if I try commenting lines 1 or 2 back in, I get a compile error.  Furthermore, I can call the functions with both const and non-const values.  These require code duplication, though.

Baz avoids this using a simple template.  I can call it using a pointer and an iterator.  However, if I never call it with a const value (ll. 5 and 6 are commented out), I am allowed to assign to the value pointed to (l. 3 yields no error).  Removing the assignment (qux, l. 4) allows me to pass const and non-cost values alike.  This is in principle fine (I could catch errors using a test-case), but it does not let the compiler know the value should be considered const and to apply optimizations accordingly.  I would prefer the caller to not have to worry about constness in this case (especially since forgetting constness is not an error and would just "inexplicably" yield slower code).

Now, I'd like something like quux, except, you know, working.  I want something with behavior similar to foo and bar, but without the code duplication.  The problem is that I get a const pointer/iterator to a non-const integer, not a pointer/iterator (const or not) to const integers.  I can leave in line 5 or (lines 8 and 9) but not both.  I would like the compiler to enforce that if I leave in any of the lines 7-9, line 5 is a compile error.

I know, I could fix this using template specializations and/or function overloads (below), but this requires me to do so (and if I forget to I might end up in the baz case except without the test-case to find the error).  The code should be easy to move around, temporarily copy for alternative implementations, etc., yet still be possible to make efficient and robust.  This also forces me to know more about my collection.

```
template<class T>
void quux_(T it)
{
        it[5] = 7; // 5
        int tmp = it[5];
}

void quux(const int* it) { quux_<const int*>(it); }
void quux(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it) { quux_<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>(it); }
```

I could also fix this by explicitly converting to a corresponding const value (though converting and iterator to the corresponding const_iterator seems to be a bit of a hassle if you don't know the collection, and C++ is not really happy with even parametrized collections, though I assume that can be fixed).  This does impose quite a bit of boiler-plate, though (I have up to 4 such parameters and dozens such functions).  Of the two alternatives, this is my preferred one, though I'd like something with the simplicity of foo and bar.

```
// template<class U> struct constify<typename std::vector<U>::iterator> { typedef typename std::vector<U>::const_iterator type; };
template<> struct constify<typename std::vector<int>::iterator> { typedef typename std::vector<int>::const_iterator type; };
template<> struct constify<std::vector<int>::const_iterator> { typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator type; };
template<class U> struct constify<U*> { typedef const U* type; };
template<class U> struct constify<const U*> { typedef const U* type; };

template<class T>
void quux(T p_it)
{
        typename constify<T>::type it = p_it;
        //it[5] = 7; // 5
        int tmp = it[5];
}
```

Does anybody have an elegant way of achieving this?  If the only solution is casting the parameter explicitly, I'd also like input on a more elegant version of constify -- I'm satisfied if it can only handle vector iterators and pointers, but it should preferably be generic in the collection base type.

Comment: something like `auto quux(T p_it) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<decltype(p_it[5])>>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately, that's a bunch of c++11 features, and even with that I couldn't think of a way that would correctly cause an error on assignment and accept non-const values from the user of the function.

Comment: ah I missed the lack of c++11 and boost...I think yours is probably the most elegant way to do it without them, these changes were made because this was such a pain without them.

Comment: Crap! I was hoping somebody smarter than I had something that resembled a solution more than a hack.  Anyway, thanks I'll probably just do the cast-thing, then.

Comment: I'm not sure if just adding a `const` will increase performance. The optimizer might be smart enough to see that you're not modifying. -> measure it. -- You could a) check if `iterator_traits<T>::value_type` is const-qualified and "static_assert" that it is (some fancy iterators won't support this kind of check, but the StdLib containers should) b) wrap the iterator in an immutable iterator wrapper.

Comment: That is of course true (even Visual Studio should be that smart).  This is not (necessarily) true, though, if it is passed to another method, especially one which has a const and a non-const version.

Comment: constness is a compile time check. I am not aware of any major compiler that exploits const qualifiers to add extra optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no way to achieve what you're trying to do, except having a template specialization.

To me a clean solution would be:

```
//const version
template<class T>
void quux(const T it)
{ }

//non const version
template<class T>
void quux( T it)
{ }
```

As I see it, this is not code duplication, the two interfaces are different, and you should offer to the client only the bare minimum he needs.

When you try to start mixing the two, it can lead only to problems. 
If you *need* to modify the parameter inside the function, give only the non const version, and the client will be able to call you with a const parameter without any problems. (non const to const cast works out of the box)

In the case you can assure you're not modifying the parameter inside your quux function, just provide the const one.

Now, const_casting the parameter to modify it inside your function is just a capital sin :-)

tldr; 
Think about what your interface exposes, and code the bare minimum.